# How to keep car seat from lifting off seat when tightening?

Tags: car-seat

We have two Britax pioneer car seats for our daughters. We've tried two different cars but have the same problem. When we tighten the straps, the seat part of the car seat lifts up off the... seat in the car. That's slightly confusing, I know.

We use the stabilizing harness (hooked to the back of the seat) and the anchor latches...  But the anchor latches only tighten on one side (so it's the same physical strap connecting both anchors).

Our other car seats have been super snug and don't move at all when we tighten the straps. These move several inches in either direction if we push on the base side to side.

Comment: Not sure what country you're in, but in the US there will be someone at any police station or hospital who can take a look at your carseat for you and tell you whether or not you're putting it in safely.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your seat is loose. Some need more pressure than others to tighten the anchor strap correctly. What I usually do is put a knee in the seat, put my full weight on it and then tighten the anchor strap in that position, with as much force as I can. I suggest you try something like that if you have not already.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the seat fit tight it might be a design problem. There are some tests and comparisons for children's seats. Some seats just stay loose because of faulty design.

But first step is to do as MrDuk said. Put your weight on the seat before tightening the belt. You can find [installation instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0jm9j4rA90k) easily with search engine.